# Should .webp images get included in my image sitemap XML when the same images are also available in more widely supported image formats?

Tags: sitemap, images

I have an image sitemap xml. This points to my `.jpg`, `.png` etc images. However, Google has a new format `.webp`. Since not all browsers support this format yet I have to keep both the `.webp` image as well as the original image on my server.

Should I also include links to the `.webp` variants of these images besides the links to the original images?

Comment: I'm not planning to use `.webp` images at all until they have 99%+ browser support.  Right now it is at 75% with major browsers such as Edge, Firefox, and Safari without support.  https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp